# Why did my mother's App Store change to Spanish when she changed her phone's language to German?

Tags: ios-appstore, internationalization, language

My mother and I both currently live in Mexico, where Spanish is the official language. We've always had our phones, tablets and computers set to English, and the App Store has always reflected our devices' language. She uses a Mexican card tied to a Mexican bank, while I still use a British card tied to a British bank.

Yesterday she changed her iPhone's language to German, and now her App Store is in Spanish. She hasn't tried changing her phone's language back to English, but why did this happen in the first place?

I've changed my iPad's language to German, which has the effect of switching the App Store language to German. Upon switching back to English, the App Store language returns to English.

I don't understand what's going on. The App Store language allegedly reflects different things depending on whom you ask, but none of those can be true:

1. It can't reflect the device's language, otherwise hers would have changed to German, not Spanish.
2. It can't reflect the language spoken in the device's current location, otherwise...

- ...mine would be in Spanish.
- ...hers would have been in Spanish since before she changed her phone's language to German.

3. It can't reflect the language spoken in the country the card is based in, otherwise...

- ...hers would have been in Spanish since before she changed her phone's language to German.
- ...changing my iPad's language to German wouldn't change my App Store language to German.

What's going on? What exactly determines App Store language, and why did my mother's change to Spanish the moment she changed her iPhone's language to German?

(Not related to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64694/app-store-language) or [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223762/how-to-change-the-language-used-on-mac-app-store) because those users have always seen the App Store in the language of the country they're in and that isn't the case here. Not related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/412854/appstore-how-to-use-english-only-interface) either because that user's experience arose from there not being an App Store version in their native language, which is not the case with German.)

Comment: Is there a VPN configured ?

Comment: Have you checked the language under Personal Information on appleid.apple.com? I suspect Apple's various stores and payment confirmation dialogs draw their language setting from there, and make wild guesses when it isn't set.

Comment: @PtitXav No, no VPN.

Comment: @pommy Will ask her to check, thanks.

Comment: @pommy Hey, sorry for the enormous delay. My mother was rather ill and her phone’s language was not a priority. She just checked; there was no language set, but she set it to German and her App Store is still in Spanish.